# Manipulation of video frames taken by Skype/FaceTime on OS X

Tags: core-image, core-video

1. Is it possible to access and modify live stream / pixel buffers /video frames on MAC OS X, so that the modified frame (i.e. change the orientation, sharpness etc.) can be accessed by applications such as FaceTime/Skype? If yes, how?
2. What are the frameworks that will be used to modify the frames as specified in point [1]? Core Video/ AV Foundation / Core Media / OpenGL?
3. Is it even possible to do this from the Application Layer itself , without writing a kernel extension driver (KEXT) for my camera device ?